# Cut beginning of a sound effect / silence

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, xna, xna-4.0

I would like to know if it is possible in XNA Framework or any other way to cut a beginning of a sound. I record sound through a microphone and I am handling the sound instance like this:

Stream is defined like this:

```
private MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
```

Is it possible to somehow modify the stream and cut beginning of the sound?

```
SoundEffect sound = new SoundEffect(stream.ToArray(), microphone.SampleRate, AudioChannels.Mono);
var soundInstance = sound.CreateInstance();
```

How would I determine which bytes to remove? Or is it somehow possible to detect "silence" / "background" and cut that out automatically before the actual person's voice can be heard?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to know the exact WaveFormat of the recorded sound. If you've got the exact WaveFormat (e.g. 16 bit pcm mono), you could iterate through all samples, check whether it is within a specific range. If all samples are for example smaller than 0.1 it is silence. If not... play the data.

Comment: Hey, I know that the Sample rate is 16000hz and it's mono. I am not sure about the bits but how would you iterate through the samples if you knew the bit size. Would I have to cast it to some other object for easier manipulation? Or would I just work with the stream?

Comment: Basically you have to know the exact format first. If you know that, you can convert the bytes in the stream to the samples. For example: If it is 16 bit pcm you have to convert always pairs of 2 bytes to an 16 bit integer. If it ieeefloat 32 bit, you have to convert pairs of 4 bytes to an float which has a range from -1 to 1. All in all, when you've got your samples, you can take a look on their value. As I said before. They won't be zero, but you can use any value like 10%. If it is louder than 10% there is no "silence".